# One-to-one relationship not joining properly on text field in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm trying to do a simple query in MS Access 2007:

```
SELECT Table1.Name, Table2.Name FROM TABLE2
INNER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE2.Name = TABLE1.NAME;
```

I know for a fact that these two fields have equal values; e.g. `table1` and `table2` both have "Mike Smith" rows. However, when I run the query no records are shown. If I go into `table2` and rewrite the name record, it will show up in the query.

Both of these tables are created by make table queries from linked CSV files.

Comment: Have you checked that there are no extra spaces? Also, are the names of the fields reserved words by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

See whether the db engine agrees that the Name values for Mike Smith are the same in both tables.

```
SELECT
    [Name] AS name_field,
    Len([Name] AS name_length,
    'TABLE1' AS source_table
FROM TABLE1
WHERE
    [Name] ALike '%Mike%'
    AND [Name] ALike '%Smith%'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [Name] AS name_field,
    Len([Name] AS name_length,
    'TABLE2' AS source_table
FROM TABLE2
WHERE
    [Name] ALike '%Mike%'
    AND [Name] ALike '%Smith%'
ORDER BY 1, 3;
```

In addition to the possibility of trailing spaces, as @JohnFx mentioned, your Name values might include invisible characters which are not spaces.  I have encountered such characters on occasion when importing from Excel data sources.

**Update**: If you're running the query using DAO, you can revise the WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE
    [Name] Like '*Mike*'
    AND [Name] Like '*Smith*'
```

However that WHERE clause would be trouble when running the query under ADO because ADO demands you use ANSI wildcards (% and _ instead of * and ?).  The ALike (ANSI Like) keyword tells the db engine to expect ANSI wildcards, so will operate the same whether the query is run under DAO or ADO.

Comment: First of all, there is no "ALike" verb in MS-Access and the wildcard character is "*" not "%"

Comment: Sorry about that. It does seem to work in Access 2007. My apologies.

Comment: Absolutely, I tried earlier but the action was forbidden without me changing my answer which didn't seem possible at the time - it works now though.